# Clone Views in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, clone, android-view, layout-inflater

I need to define something like view classes at runtime in Android. May an example be a TextView with a defined text size and color (definition is not inside the app, it must be outside). Then I want to instantiate some of those same looking views.

My first idea was using javassist-android, but that seems not to be working for Android views.
My second idea to make an instance of the TextView (with defined text size and color) and clone this instance when I need a TextView. But cloning (instances of) views also doesn't seem to be possible for Android views.
My third idea, inflating views, only works for inflating elements via xml...

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Best regards

Comment: use custom views , extend view or textview and use that in your xml layout or add programattically

Comment: please read first three lines again

Comment: The suggestion by @r7v seems to be what you want. You should probably explain your comment better, *"please read first three lines again"*. I read them several times and don't see the problem.

Comment: I want to create something like view classes when the application is running.  some properties of all these views will be requested from outside of the app. I want add many same looking views during runtime, programmatically, and some view properties (color, text,...) are not defined before the app starts.

Comment: Yes, you create the classes and extend whatever view class you need, then pass the data (size, color, etc...) to it at runtime and create instances of those classes.

Comment: But when instantiating a new view, I always must set the color (and text size, etc etc) again. Color, size and textviews are just examples ;)